# NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' in Rails when running on Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I create a demo rails application and generate scaffolding for the Post model. Then when I try to run `rake`, the integration tests fail with this error message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<Enumerable::Enumerator:0xb68278a8>
```

How can I get the demo rails application to run?

I'm trying to create a development environment to mirror an old production server, so I'm using a bunch of old versions. I'm following [a tutorial](http://www.akitaonrails.com/2007/12/12/rolling-with-rails-2-0-the-first-full-tutorial#.U1_RYR__5k-) on Rails 2.0.2 with Ruby 1.8.7.

The commands to create and test the demo application are as follows:

```
rails blog
cd blog
./script/generate scaffold Post title:string body:text
rake db:migrate
rake
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [forum post](http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=24179) and a [blog post](http://www.tatvartha.com/2009/05/ruby-187-nomethoderror-undefined-method-for-enumerableenumerator/) that describe this as a bug in Ruby 1.8.7. They suggest similar fixes, so I created a new file `blog/config/initializers/ruby187_compat.rb` with the following code:

```
unless '1.9'.respond_to?(:force_encoding) 
    String.class_eval do 
        begin 
            remove_method :chars 
        rescue NameError 
            # OK
        end 
    end 
end
```

Now the tests pass.

It looks like the String class in Ruby 1.8.7 got a [new method `chars()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-chars) that somehow calls [the `force_encoding()` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.1/String.html#method-i-force_encoding), which wasn't introduced until Ruby 1.9.1. I guess some code got incorrectly backported.